# c# wpf IValueConverter and property attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, attributes, ivalueconverter

I have a text box that is bound to a property (eventually a lot of those). The property is a numerical value. When displaying this numerical value i would like to add a unit to it (like V,mV, C etc) and optionally scale it (as for example 3200mV=3.2V). Currently I am using one value converter and supplying a unit as a converter parameter, however i would still need a converter to pass it back.

However what i would like to do is add a custom attribute to a property with the required scale and unit. Something like this:

```
[Unit("mV")]
[Scale(0.1)]
public uint MyProperty
{
    get{ return myProperty}
    set
    {
       if(value==myProperty)
         return;
       myProperty=value;
       OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");    
    }
}
```

However I don't know how could it be possible to pass such information to the converter (and if it even is possible)?

Or what other possibilities could there be to do this in a nice way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the attribute values from the UnitAttribute and ScaleAttribute, the value converter must use Reflection and has to know the name of the class these properties are in and the name of the specific property to convert.

You can add a DependencyProperty for the class name to your value converter and use it as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MyUnitConverter x:Key="myUnitConverter" ClassName="MyNamespace.MyClass" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and then use the converter on the property and also pass the name of the property as the ConverterParameter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource myUnitConverter},
    ConverterParameter=MyProperty}" />
```

Then it should be possible from the converter to find the values used in the attributes and convert the property accordingly.

```
public class MyUnitConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    // add dependency property ClassName as string

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo info)
    {
        // use dependency property ClassName and (string)parameter 
        // as property name to get the attribute values using Reflection.
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. this actually answers another question that i had: how to get the type of the target property when i need to convert back.

Comment: @xnonamex My answer is not complete but it should guide you in the right direction. The key is to get the information to the value converter object. I hope you know how to get the attribute values with Reflection. If not, I am sure you can find an answer to that on this site.

Comment: I'll figure that out eventually.... will look into it. As long as i know in which direction to think should be fine. :)